# Are there any security benefits to enabling the PIN on an eSIM?

Tags: phone, simcard

For physical SIMs, I'm aware of a number of security benefits to enabling the SIM PIN, because for an attacker with access to a lost or stolen SIM, a PIN prevents transferring the SIM to a different phone, where they could:

- Gain access to existing voice mail stored on the service.
- Receive new SMS (including 2FA tokens sent by SMS).
- Make premium phone calls to numbers they can profit from.
- Access any other data stored on the SIM (less relevant with modern phones that typically don't store things like contacts on SIMs anymore)

But since an eSIM can never be removed from the device, and assuming the device itself is locked, such threats are not feasible. However, I noticed that it is still possible to enable the PIN on an eSIM, and I was able to find out the default PIN from my provider. So I'm wondering if there are any actual security benefits gained by enabling it?

Comment: I suppose it would help add an extra layer of security, since bypassing a phone's lock screen is not necessarily all that difficult.

Comment: **an eSIM can never be removed** I am not sure but in the beginning an eSIM was a separate chip soldered to the mainboard. If that is still the case somebody with soldering experience may be able to desolder it and move it to a different phone. Does anybody know if such an attack would be feasible on an eSIM?

Comment: You won't receive incoming calls on locked eSIM.

Comment: @defalt That's interesting. Does that also mitigate the silent SMS attack vector?

Comment: @forest According to GSM specification, the `RUN GSM ALGORITHM` function which is used during the procedure for authenticating the SIM to a GSM network and to calculate a cipher key shall not be executable unless successful cardholder verification procedure has been performed. This makes it invisible to the base transceiver station to receive either calls or SMS.